# Cómo edito los valores de un checkbox en otro componente en Angular

Tags: array, angular, checkbox

Tengo un formulario en el cual se tiene que seleccionar checkbox, a los checkbox seleccionados los guardo en un arreglo, recorro ese arreglo y hago un POST a mi servicio. Hasta ahí me funciona todo bien. Ahora quiero que cada valor del checkbox que guardé en un principio se pueda editar en otro componente. En mi `html` para guardar tengo lo siguiente:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #categoryForm="ngForm">
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Nombre CV</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="nombrecv" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre de su cv para realizar la configuración" value="Personalizado">
     </mat-form-field>
     <mat-accordion>
          <mat-expansion-panel class="expansion" hideToggle *ngFor="let bloque of arregloBloques | keyvalue">
               <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                         Bloque: {{bloque.key}}
                    </mat-panel-title>
                    <mat-panel-description>
                         Despliegue para obtener mayor información
                    </mat-panel-description>
               </mat-expansion-panel-header>
               <mat-card class="tarjeta-informacion">
                    <div class="informacion" *ngFor="let propiedad of arregloBloques[bloque.key] ">
                         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" formControlName="propiedad" name="miDataInterior" 
                         (change)="$event.target.checked ? agregar(propiedad.bloque, propiedad.atributo, propiedad.mapeo) : quitar(propiedad.isSelected)">
                          <p class="nombre">
                               <b>Bloque:</b> {{propiedad.bloque}}
                               <b>Atributo:</b> {{propiedad.atributo}}
                          </p>
                    </div>
               </mat-card>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
     </mat-accordion>
     <div class="col text-center">
          <button mat-raised-button class="botones" color="primary" [disabled]='!form.valid' (click)="PostConfiguracionPersonalizada()">Guardar</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

En mi `.ts` para `agregar`, `quitar` del arreglo y hacer el `POST`tengo esto:

```
//Agrego valores seleccionados de checkbox al arreglo
 agregar(bloque: string, atributo: string, mapeo: string) {
    console.log(this.form.value.nombrecv);
    console.log(this.form.value.propiedad);

    const data = {
      idDocente: 1,
      bloque: bloque,
      atributo: atributo,
      visible_cv_personalizado: this.form.value.propiedad,
      mapeo: mapeo,
      cv: 1,
      nombre_cv: this.form.value.nombrecv
    };

    let conf = this.miDataInterior.push(data);
    console.log(conf);
  }

//Si deselecciona el valor se quita del arreglo
  quitar(atributo) {
    this.miDataInterior.splice(this.miDataInterior.indexOf(atributo), 1);
    console.log(this.miDataInterior);
  }

//Recorro el arreglo con los checkbox guardados y los guardo
  PostConfiguracionPersonalizada() {
    console.log(this.miDataInterior);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.miDataInterior.length; i++) {
      let clave = this.miDataInterior[i];
      console.log('GUARDADO', clave);
    }
  }
```

Como dije hasta ahí todo bien, ahora quiero que en otro componente de edición poder marcar los checkbox que guardé en mi arreglo. Para poder editar en mi `html` del componente de edición tengo lo mismo que el de arriba

En mi componente para editar en el`.ts` recupero lo que guarde en mi arreglo, y estoy intentando usar `this.form.patchValue` para pasar mis datos guardados, con esto solo puedo recuperar el nombre de mi formulario, pero no se como marcar los checkboxs que guardé antes, por ahora tengo esto:

```
getCheckboxGuardado() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      nombrecv: this.checkboxGuardados[0].nombre_cv,
    });
}
```

Para que me entiendan mejor les dejo aqui un ejemplo de lo que tengo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjrbmu?file=src/edita-configuracion/edita-configuracion.component.ts

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: [EjemploMinimoVerificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)

Comment: @AndreaJimenez ya lo modifiqué y agregué un ejemplo de lo que tengo en stackblitz. Espero ahora se me pueda entender mejor. Gracias!